# Why does "test" come before "paul" in lexicographical compare

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort an array of strings. I was doing some tests and I found something that I did not expect. I can not explain it.

```
if ("test" < "paul")
{
  cout << "test is less than paul" << endl;
}
```

Why is "test" less than "paul"? 'p' has a lower ASCII value than 't'. It also comes before p in the alphabet. The string length is also the same in both cases.

I am using swap() to sort the array in alphabetical order(well trying to). I can not use sort(), I need to use swap.

update:
in the above example I used a pointer, but this is my actual code.

```
DynamicArray<string> sectionName;  //declaration
swap(alreadySeen[i].sectionName[j],alreadySeen[i].sectionName[i]); //usage
```

This is obviously not the complete code, don't want to get lost in the details

Comment: You're comparing pointers, not strings

Comment: Because this isn't a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: "test" comes before "paul"... in memory !

Comment: @KIIV in this example it was a pointer, but it is also true for strings. alreadySeen[i].sectionName[j][0] < alreadySeen[i].sectionName[i][0] I updated the code.

Comment: Sorry guys, the issue is the loop (sorting algorithm). but good points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always compile with warnings enabled.**

```
 warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
     if ("test" < "paul")
                  ^~~~~~
```

You are not comparing strings, you are comparing memory addresses. Here's a [wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UU0j5PAgNFQcVX0f).

In order to achieve what you want:

- If you **need** to use C-style strings, use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

  ```
  if(std::strcmp("test", "paul") < 0) { /* ... */ }
  ```
- If you can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you can simply write:

  ```
  if(std::string{"test"} < std::string{"paul"}) { /* ... */ }
  ```

Comment: using std::string seems excessive to me. But there is an interesting potential bonus: Are strings locale sensitive? Comparisons between *words* (semantically) generally may depend on locale.

Comment: Thanks I like your answer. I updated my code, I used strings not pointers. I guess I just used the pointers for the example.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I originally did it the way you said and it produces that error.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Nevermind, I guess my sorting loops are messed up. If I do "string test = "test"; string paul = "paul" it does work how you say.